# Assert the execution order of private methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, mocking

I want to test that a method `Foo`, that calls three private methods `boo1`, `boo2`, `boo3` is indeed calling them in this exact order (this is a simplification of the real scenario).

To test the sequence I am planning on using `InSequence` method of the `Mock` object.

To test the private method i am planning on using the [`PrivateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=mstest-net-1.2.0) class.

I have no idea how to combine those two; here what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work!

```
public class TestedClass
{
    private void _boo1(object someParam)
    {
        //some logic
    }
    private void _boo2(object someParam)
    {
        //some logic
    }
    private void _boo3(object someParam)
    {
        //some logic
    }
    public void Foo(object someParam)
    {
        _boo1(someParam);
        _boo2(someParam);
        _boo3(someParam);
    }
}
```

And here the test method that I've created so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSequence()
{
        var sequence = new MockSequence();
        var mockedObject = new Mock<TestedClass>();
        PrivateObject obj = new PrivateObject(mockedObject);
        mockedObject.Object.Foo(It.IsAny<Object>());

        mockedObject.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => obj.Invoke("_boo1", BindingFlags.Default, It.IsAny<Object>()));
        mockedObject.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => obj.Invoke("_boo2", BindingFlags.Default, It.IsAny<Object>()));
        mockedObject.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => obj.Invoke("_boo3", BindingFlags.Default, It.IsAny<Object>()));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this problem. Maybe it is similar to yours:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602264/using-moq-to-verify-calls-are-made-in-the-correct-order

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking to test the sequence of private methods not public ones

Comment: A private method(s) is an implementation detail that should be hidden to the users of the class. Testing private methods breaks encapsulation. In your case if you change the implementation of `Foo`, you must change your unit test too, which makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: If you would not mock your private methods: Would there be some criteria by which you could observe whether the three methods were called in the proper order?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use System.IO to write status messages to a log file?  You can also use System.Diagnostics to get the name of the method you're currently in:

```
string methodName = new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name
```

Comment: but this is a unit test! i have to change the tested method for that ?