# Mocking sealed classes without public constructors?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

The particular class I'm testing depends upon the HttpSessionState object.

The HttpSessionState class has no public constructors.  The class under test is only using this object as a NameValue store.  The class is used in an ASMX web service to return information for a particular method.

I'm thinking about creating a facade around the HttpSessionState class where I can provide a Dictionary <string, string> instead of the Session object in testing.

Is this a good idea or standard practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, as the old saying goes, there's nothing that can't be solved by adding another layer of abstraction.  I usually just hide the type behind an interface where the interface's methods are the only ones needed to perform the actions I want on that type.

Just mock the interface that hides HttpSessionState, and do Asserts on the uses of the interface, in Rhino Mocks it's just AssertWasCalled(d => ....) etc.

Comment: "there's nothing that can't be solved by adding another layer of abstraction" - except "to much layers of abstractions" =)

Comment: I believe the original was, "there's nothing that another level of indirection can't solve."  At some point though you won't be able to test a level, such as what you're hiding httpsessionstate in.  Not familiar with it but guessing you can't really unit test it, but you can test the SUT if it's using a type like this to do "something".

Comment: I don't care about original, it's just true =)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sub-class of the HttpSessionStateBase class. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/690934/1036689) shows how to implement this for Moq, but you can still use the MockHttpSession class with your Rhino Mocks (I assume. I haven't used Rhino Mocks).

```
public class MockHttpSession : HttpSessionStateBase
{
    Dictionary<string, object> sessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override object this[string name]
    {
        get { return sessionStorage[name]; }
        set { sessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }
}
```

A fairly extensive discussion about how to mock .NET classes can be found at Scott Hanselman's blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx).

Comment: is the HttpSessionStateBase class is available for web services?

Comment: @PeterSmith HttpSessionStateBase is in the System.Web namespace, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock any type even sealed ones using [Microsoft's Moles Isolation framework for .NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/).  Takes a little work to setup but might be better than adding another layer of abstraction.  Mocking `HttpContext` and `HttpSessionState` using moles is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487847/1004119).  There is another similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1981620/1004119).

Comment: I am not sure that to get another one project dependency, read as "brand new isolation framework" is simplier solution (read as better) that one tiny abstraction.

Comment: @Restuta, yeah, you're probably right, but it's an option and answers at least the title of the question "Mocking sealed classes"