# Microsoft Unit Testing for ASP.NET with VS2012

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am ripping apart and putting back together a large website and want to take this opportunity to do some test driven development as the site is recreated.  The issue that I am running into is how. A lot of the items that I need to test deal with session variables (or other variables) that are being set when a user logs in.  But if I am testing an individual page I don't ever log in.

For example:

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:64769/UsersDetail.aspx")]
public void GetCompanyId_Test()
{
    var testID = GetCompanyID();

    Assert.AreEqual("123456789", testID);

}
```

Now, the problem is that in order for GetCompanyID to work, it has to have variables available that are set at login.

Is this possible?  Do I have to mock up the data in some way ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the option in this situation is best solved by Mocking

Comment: If you are recreating the site why are you using Session at all? Personally if I was rewriting a legacy website the first thing I would do is to get rid of any state from it (which is exactly what the session introduces) and make it more RESTful. What's the point of rewriting some code and make the same mistakes this code originally had?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov some things pretty much have to be stored in a session.

Comment: @AetherMcLoud, what kind of things? Databases or distributed caching (if you care about performance) is much better in handling those scenarios. And in addition to that it makes your application completely stateless. And you know the benefit of having a stateless application? It's called scalability.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov AFAIK cache-data can be accessed by anyone, not just the one who created it, so sensible user data would be better in a session? I'm not too well-versed in caching :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to change the GetCompanyID function to use some variables that are filled by the session in the livesystem, and by your testsetup in the unit test system. Alas, you can't mock HttpSessionState in ASP.NET - see here: [How do I mock/fake the session object in ASP.Net Web forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981426/how-do-i-mock-fake-the-session-object-in-asp-net-web-forms)

Another idea would be to actually do the loginaction in the testsetup.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much but was wondering it there was another way to do it