# Why does my unit test complete successfully without running the test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing

I am getting the error below when I run a unit test:

> completed successfully without running the test. This can occur when
>   configuring the Web application for testing fails (an ASP.NET server
>   error occurs when processing the request), or when no ASP.NET page is
>   executed (the URL may point to an HTML page, a Web service, or a
>   directory listing). Running tests in ASP.NET requires the URL to
>   resolve to an ASP.NET page and for the page to execute properly up to
>   the Load event. The response from the request is stored in the file
>   'WebRequestResponse_populateData.html' with the test results;
>   typically this file can be opened with a Web browser to view its
>   contents.

I'm not sure what this means. Do you have any pointers I could look into?

Comment: providing what unit testing framework you are using and what the unit test was doing might help get you some answers

Comment: see this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051028/unit-test-configuration-for-asp-net-application

Comment: The title says the test runs successfully, but the question content says you're getting an error.  Well, which is it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051028/unit-test-configuration-for-asp-net-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the attribute UrlToTest to the Url In test. 
Like:

```
[UrlToTest("URL your testing")]
```