# Where is the NUnit.Mocks documentation?

Tags: documentation, nunit, nunit-mocks

Where is the documentation for NUnit's mocking library, NUnit.Mocks?

I can't find anything in their [official documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=documentation) or [wiki](http://www.nunit.org/wiki/doku.php).

Comment: This question might be moot, since Charlie Poole stated (http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2eac69ad9f35c3c9/d76235caaf8b4af8) in 2008: "I generally fix bugs but don't enhance it, since I want folks to look at the more complete mock frameworks like Rhino or NMock once they get the basic idea."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [I have been told recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168887/c-mocking-framework-simple-with-informative-exceptions) Nunit.Mocks are not meant to be used for serious applications. Given it's obvious limitations you're better off with a [different framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453005/mocking-tools-for-c-sharp-on-net) anyway...

Comment: apparently Wikipedia didn't like the mocking frameworks page, so here's a similar list here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561524/what-are-the-predominant-net-3-0-mocking-frameworks

Answer (score 6):

> NUnit.Mocks was originally developed for internal use in NUnit's own
>   tests, although we no longer use it for that purpose.
>
> In addition, it has been useful as a teaching tool, allowing users to
>   gain familiarity with mocking techniques before moving on to more
>   serious frameworks.
>
> For production use, we recommend you install a full-featured mock
>   object framework.
>
> The NUnit project now uses NSubstitute and NUnit.Mocks is no longer
>   being developed.

Source: [NUnit.Mocks 2.6.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Mocks)