# Using moq framework in Visual Studio 2010 express

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to use the moq framework with Visual Studio 2010 express. The reason for not use Visual Studio 2012/2013 is that I have to develop my application in Windows XP.

Since my VS version is express, I cannot use nuget package manager. Because of this, I need to obtain the moq frameork in a different way.

I have tried to download the source from GitHub and build it with a 2013 version of Visual Studio that I have in other PC. The problem is that the latest version of moq framework needs, at least, .NET v4.0, but I need to build it for .NET v3.0, since I need a .dll I can use in WinXP. I have tried to build moq for .NET v3.0 (with this VS 2013) but I have had a lot of errors.

My question is, how can I obtain a previous version of moq framework, which I can build for .NET v3.0?

Comment: you can download moq binaries here https://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list?can=4&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the oldest version of moq (binaries) here https://code.google.com/p/moq/downloads/list?can=4&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount
and needs a .NET version greater than 3.0.

I think it is not possible to use moq framework with .NET v3.0.

EDIT:
Yes, it's not possible:
[What are the predominant .NET 3.0 mocking frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561524/what-are-the-predominant-net-3-0-mocking-frameworks)